# Populated user reading as undefined

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am having an issue with displaying my user's profile picture on their post. Whenever I would do this

```
Cannot read property 'profilePicture' of undefined
```

I have already populated the field, but I get this error regardless. I have already checked that user is stored.

Some code related to this issue.

```
//index.js
router.get('/' ,async (req, res) => {
      const articles = await Article.find({title: regex}).sort({ createdAt: 'desc'}).populate("user")
      res.render('articles/index', { articles: articles })
})
```

```
//The area causing the error
<p class="mb-2">
    <img src="/uploads/profile/<%= article.user.profilePicture %>" class="img-circle" style="width: 50px; height:50px;   border-radius: 75%;">
    <%= article.author %>
</p>
```

```
//article.js
const ArticleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },

  author: {
    type: String
  },

  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },

  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },

  slug: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },

  user : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },

});
```

```
//user.js
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    profilePicture: {
        type: String
    },

    imgType: {
        type: String
    },

    articles: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Article' }]

});
```

In advance, thanks.

Comment: Are you checking articles.user.profilePicture? Update the question with the statement causing the error.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the schema definition of Article and User as well.

Comment: I have added the user.js and article.js to the post as well as the error part of the index.ejs.

Comment: if you `console.log` the article without populating, is it returning the correct article with a userId?